# Issue with UTF-8 encoding using PHP + MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8, multibyte

I moved data from MySQL 4 (they were originally set to `latin2` encoding) to MySQL 5 and set the encoding to UTF-8. It looks good in [phpMyAdmin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpMyAdmin), and UTF-8 is okay. However, there are question marks instead of some characters on the website! The website encoding is also set to UTF-8, so I don’t understand where the problem is.

PHP and HTML files are also set to UTF-8.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Oh, a classic! Like the day when the last IE6 instance is deleted, I will celebrate the day when the last PHP script is moved to PHP 6. (In this far, far future I can then tell my grandchildren about the ISO-8859 monster and its sidekick named Codepage.)

Comment: im sorry but I of course tried SET NAMES 'utf8' ..on database, didnt help. :(

Comment: Well, you have to execute that query every time your script connects to the database before you execute other queries...

Comment: Related question with excellent answer on all the things you need to check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: This [post](http://bit.ly/1ma0wIz) explains how to configure and work with UTF-8 in PHP and MySQL. Hope that saves your time.

Comment: See "question mark" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Comment: @Sebastian Viereck: The link is broken (*"Die Seite konnte nicht gefunden werden"*)

Answer (score 30):

Try the query

```
SET NAMES utf8
```

before any query in your application.

Comment: not neccessary. Setting db encoding to utf8 and without using `SET NAMES` works fine for my application.

Comment: Yep, most common problem. The check your client encoding or set it with the SQL Command valya already posted. It is enough to add it before every block of statements that you send at once.

Comment: @Mauris, of course, your way is better and faster, but mine is the most simple solution which can be archieved in every language and environment without rtfm :)

Comment: Are the question marks inserted by the database or the browser? I always forget that part... ;)

Comment: This worked for me, but it was not clear exactly how this was done. Therefore I added a new answer with *exact* PHP syntax below.

Answer (score 25):

On my server, adding these to my PHP file had no effect:

```php
ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8');
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

But everything worked perfectly once I added this to the top of my PHP file:

```php
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

Note: I am using encoding `utf8_general_ci` in my database, but `utf8_unicode_ci` works the same for me.

Comment: where i can write it ?

Comment: just write it on top of your index.php file

Comment: Just edited my answer to make it more clear that these changes are made to your php file.

Answer (score 13):

Try setting the MySQL connection to UTF-8:

```
SET NAMES 'utf8'
```

And send explicit UTF-8 headers, just in case your server has some other default settings:

```php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to set your PHP and HTML files to utf-8.

You just have to set your output encoding to UTF-8 and the browser will display appropriately.

In HTML:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

In PHP:

```php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

When you get a string that is UTF-8 from the MySQL table, it will be UTF-8 all the way to browser output unless you convert the encoding. It's the way that the browser interprets it.

Comment: If you store special characters in your PHP scripts, make sure your scripts are UTF-8 encoded or they won't display correctly. Some IDEs do this automatically and it IS a requirement

Answer (score 2):

When you show UTF-8 characters on a website, but tell the browser to interpret them as [Latin-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) (or [Latin-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-2)) you see this kind of gibberish: `ÃƒÂŸ`

When you show Latin-1 (or Latin-2) characters on a website, but tell the browser to interpret them as UTF-8, you see question marks.

So my guess is that you switched everything to UTF-8 (I mean, you told the database engine, the web server and the browser you would be using UTF-8), but you didn't actually convert the strings to UTF-8.

Do what [Darkerstar said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707792/issue-with-utf-8-encoding-using-php-mysql/1708502#1708502). Convert your dump to UTF-8 ([Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B) can do that easily) and import it again.

Comment: I know this is an old question.  I answered for the sake of those that get here with the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");
```

Adding this line at the end of my "connection.php" solved my problem.

My connection file's complete code is:

```
<?php
# FileName="Connection_php_mysql.htm"
# Type="MYSQL"
# HTTP="true"
$hostname_test = "localhost";
$database_test = "test";
$username_test = "username";
$password_test = "password";
$test = mysql_pconnect($hostname_test, $username_test, $password_test) or trigger_error(mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");
?>
```

My database collation is "utf8_general_ci".

Pages are "dreamweaver default utf8" and "unicode normalisation form=C (Canonical Decomposition)".

Comment: What do you mean by *"Pages are "dreamweaver default utf8""*? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem recently (I hope it’s the same problem you are having), and I tried many ways, but at the end what worked was really simple.

Convert your dumped SQL file to UTF-8 format and then import it.

BTW: I used [Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B) for the conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Put a [.htaccess file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.htaccess) in your web-site root with content:
*AddDefaultCharset UTF-8*

and

in your dbconfig set after connection to the database:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like setting every SQL *database*, *table*, and *field* to UTF-8 in MySQL is good enough. Very annoying.

I ended up forcing the issue to solve encoding problems:

I had to use this *every* place I open the database:

```php
$db->set_charset("utf8");
```

And that worked. Finally.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fix. Set the header to `header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` Then print your content using `utf8_decode($content)`. You must have the two to make it work.

Comment: are you sure you don't mean `utf8_encode`? Cause that's what finally fixed it for me.

Answer (score -1):

Putting:

```
$conn->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

Where $conn is my Mysqli connection
in my config file helped.

Comment: this answer is wrong. Besides, it's a duplicate. Please don't post answers that are just duplicate existing answers

Comment: It worked for me, how is it wrong?

Comment: [This is the preferred way to change the charset. Using mysqli_query() to set it (such as SET NAMES utf8) is not recommended.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php)