# Decode a special character...?

Tags: php, decode

I am pulling through the field item_name from a database. It should read : "Reminisce Basic £11.99 + Card £4.99 + Free"

But when its coming through the £ signs are coming out as � is there a method to decode this to at least make it look like a £ sign?

My code is as follows :

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","","");
    mysql_select_db("", $con);

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT custom, item_name from paypalsub WHERE custom = '$_SESSION[uid]'");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $sub_type = $row['item_name'];
    }
?>
<h2>You are currently subscribed to : <?php echo ($sub_type); ?></h2>
```

The H2 is outputting it like this :

> You are currently subscribed to : Reminisce Basic �11.99 + Card �4.99 + Free

Any help.. Much appreciated.

Comment: are you setting the page charset? something like  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

Comment: Yeah, the page has this : <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem in utf-8 encoding PHP + MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707792/problem-in-utf-8-encoding-php-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1.) Are you sending the output in UTF-8?

```
header('content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8')
```

#### 2.) Have you also set the MySQL connection to UTF-8?

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf-8'");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with utf8_encode($string) or utf8_decode($string). I never remember which one to use, sorry.

Comment: I tried utf8_decode($sub_type) - still comes out with the same character issue.

I might have a look at encoding it for db insertion

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your database is in some encoding (not UTF-8) and your output is in a different encoding.

Find out which encoding the database uses.

Comment: Hi, The db Collation is set to : utf8_general_ci